# Why dosn't my php code echo "You are now logged in"?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, authentication

I try to make a login system with php and a txt file but when i try the code it will not work. Instead if echo "you are now logged in" it echo "dosn't work". Why is that so?

**users.txt file**

```
david
123123
---------------
nicklas
1222
---------------
hello
wwe
```

**php**

```
<?php 
    $lines = file('users.txt');
    $data = array();
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
            if(trim($lines[$i]) === trim($username)) {
                $data[0] = $lines[$i]; //username
                $data[1] = $lines[$i+1]; //password
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (($data[0] === $username) && ($data[1] === $password)) {
        echo "You are logged in";
    }
    else {
        echo "dosn't work";
    }
?>
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gothic+A1" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <p>With password and username</p>
        <br />
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="textfield" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="text" class="textfield" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" id="btn" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I already know how to make a login form with phpmyadmin and sql but i would like to be able to store data in a txt file

Comment: You realise you've just put all the usernames/passwords in plain text, in a world readable file, at the document root?

Comment: Try echoing out what you're getting in `$data`, `$username`, and `$password`. By the way, make sure you're not using cleartext passwords, especially in a text file.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using this, as opposed to a database along with `password_hash()/password_verify()` ?

Comment: I think the reason could be that you use `===` in the `if` before echoing. I am unsure, but maybe the types of the variables differ, therefore, `===` fails, try changing to `==`. By the way, migrating from MySQL to plain text is certainly not a good idea.

Comment: You don't need the password, you could login using username `---------------` and password `hello`

Comment: `hello` is going to have some monumental issues when `david` changes their password to "hello"

Comment: As for the actual error - you sort of got it - you need to use `trim()` on `$lines` as it has a new line on each entry (from `file()`)

Comment: Thanks for all answers, i realise what i have been doing wrong, and why i use a txt file is because my teacher forced us to use txt as a database

Comment: Although this is a terrible idea compared to using a database - if it's for an assignment you can try to make it more robust/secure by 1) storing the data in a CSV format - there are functions for parsing that at least 2) store the file outside of the document root and 3) a little redundant if the file is outside the docroot, but if you call it something like `.htusers` Apache will, by default, deny access to that file (it denies access to anything beginning `.ht`).

Comment: ... and yes, you can still use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` when you're storing the passwords in a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to trim the excess spaces of your username and password.

```
$data[0] = trim($lines[$i]); //username
$data[1] = trim($lines[$i+1]); //password
```

Edit: I'm assuming this is for educational purposes and you're not planning on having accounts in a text file. If so, I recommend looking into databases and hashing password with PHP.

Comment: thanks, it worked. However what risk is there to store accounts in txt files?

Comment: @Simon, did you really just ask what the risk was...? I could go to; `yoursite.com/users.txt` and read the whole thing, in plain text, right in front of me...

Comment: @SamSwift웃 ooh yeah that's right, is there any way to prevent that without using a database. I feel so stupid haha

Comment: It's not clear cut and primarily reliant on having the strongest, stablest server ever (and strong and stable doesn't always work), but... Create a file with a random extension (for example u_sers.hgft) and set up htaccess so this cannot be accessed via the browser using a FilesMatch clause - also nest it deep within some random file structure, security through obscurity

Comment: @Simon - also **NEVER** store passwords as plain text - hash them, one way only!

Comment: Okey thanks, so if i hash the passwords, there should be no security problems by using a txt file?

Comment: As other comments have said - just hashing is not enough, you need extra security if you are storing in your web dir, consider naming the file `.htusers` (as @CD001 has said) as apache ignores (and doesn't show) anything starting `.ht`